# Dell Studio 1555 not starting up

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, kubuntu, dell-studio

This is a 3-year-old laptop. I never had a big problem with it until now. I updated Kubuntu the night before yesterday. And Firefox got updated to version 18 and a few other related packages got updated. Then I shut down the laptop and restarted it, but it failed to start. I could hear the fan and the hard disk and the optical disk drive initialize. And the power button also lighted up. But there was no video - no POST or BIOS menu.

I even opened the laptop up to the point when only the motherboard was the only thing attached to the base cover. I took it to the technician this evening. He checked it casually, and said that it might be a motherboard problem and will cost quite a bit to fix. Though he was not sure and said that he will give me a call after confirming the problem. Has anyone else had the same problem? What was it and what was the fix?

Comment: If it does not even POST then all of yesterdays updating is irrelevant. I would take that out of the post. Also, check it it is under or over 3 years old because standard Dell warranty is 3 years.

Comment: Its more 3 years an 3 months old. And anyways I got a warranty of 1 year on this machine and didn't care to extend it. I can also understand that mentioning the updating of software is irrelevant. But just mentioned it to give the context.

Comment: If your laptop have VGA or HDMI ports, connect the device and check your laptop with an external monitor that you sure about VGA chip. I think the high voltage of your device is damaged.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't beep during boot, it isn't posting and your mobo is dead. At least, it is in a desktop, but it's a laptop, which means it could be a battery issue. Take the battery out and run it off the mains and try again. Also, try a new power supply (mains adapter) as this can cause the same symptoms. Make sure the adapter is compatible or you may cause more damage.

If it DOES beep (once) like normal, then you have a dead screen.

Dell warranty is pretty good and you usually get 3 years. Their products are also very good as self destructing just as the warranty runs out. I'd call them. If you are only a few weeks out, they may even repair it for free.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already tried draining the power and trying again. The result was the same- it didn't start. Also tried a new adapter at the technicians place. And I got a warranty of 1 year on this laptop and didn't care to extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the laptop back from the technician. The repair cost Rs. 2200. He said that he replaced an IC on the motherboard. Although, honestly I don't believe him. When I asked what IC he changed. He replied that he did not remember the name. He said that he took the faulty IC, showed it, got the replacement, and fixed the replacement IC.